# Regarding the DEPENDS.txt in CTAN upload

Tags: ctan, dependencies

Recently I got a suggestion from one GitHub issue that I should add a `DEPENDS.txt` to my packages, and I am planing to do so. However, there is one thing that confuses me.

Suppose that there are two packages `package1` and `package2`, and in the `DEPENDS.txt` of `package1` one has the line `hard package3`. Then if I have `hard package1` in the `DEPENDS.txt` of `package2`, do I still need to write `hard package3`, or shall `package3` be automatically updated when updating `package1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least for TeX Live, indirect dependencies are taken into account. So in your case, there would be no need to make `package2` explicitly depend on `package3`.

Comment: Thank you for this!